# Logical order an MDX query is processed

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

What is the order of evaluation of the clauses within an `MDX` script?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.A AS ...
  MEMBER measures.B AS ...
  SET S1 AS ...
SELECT 
  {
    measures.A
   ,measures.B
   ,measures.x
  } ON COLUMNS
  {S1} HAVING <condition> on ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ({S2})
```

1. `FROM`
2. `WHERE`
3. `WITH`
4. `SELECT`
5. `HAVING`

?

But maybe not that simple as a `MEMBER` and a `SET` are dealt with differently in terms of context - so if this order is correct how does context tie in?

Comment: Would like to hear a comment from the person who voted to close this post because it doesn't appear to be about programming. I'd struggle to find an `MDX` question that is _more_ about programming than the order in which the script processes: its fundamental to the way all `MDX` scripts should be structured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say:

1. FROM (including potential subselects)
2. WHERE
3. SETs and MEMBER location in the WITH clause
4. Build the list of tuples for all query axes (columns, rows, ...) in parallel, ignoring NON EMPTY and HAVING
5. Cell values for all axis intersections
6. Remove tuples from the axes as requested by NON EMPTY and HAVING for each axis.

By "member location" in step 3, I mean the information that the member exists at all, and in which hierarchy and possibly under which parent it is located in the hierarchy. This does not involve the member definition expression. That will be evaluated in step 5 and 6. But the location is needed for step 4.

The parallel evaluation of the axes means that there is no relation between axes in the query processing.

Also note that this is the conceptual view. Physically, step 6 may happen during the processing of step 4, or whatever the optimizer decides is a proper execution order, as long as the result would be the same.

Comment: +1 `conceptual view` is perfect as this is what needs to be kept in mind when building these scripts - that, rather than the processor point of view, is what I'm currently trying to get my head around.

Comment: @FrankPI not mentioned in the OP but could you please add in `subselect`s?

Comment: @FrankPI a custom named set in the `WITH` clause is not context aware because axes tuples are created in step 4 ?

Comment: @whytheq Subselects are a part of the FROM, I extended my answer. And named sets are sensitive to the context change from WHERE but not those from query axes.

Comment: @FrankPl - Do you have any blog references? I am interested to learn about it in details.