# Measure lacking context

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I am struggling to force the measure `CountTopPromos` to be contextual.
Currently it is calculating a count of *all* the tuples in `TopX`. Against the version of AdWrks that I am running this is 14.

How do I force a context, of the current year, onto the measure `CountTopPromos`

```
WITH 
  SET FullSet AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
      * 
        [Promotion].[Promotion].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
    ) 
  SET TopX AS 
    Generate
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
     ,TopPercent
      (
          [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
        * 
          Extract
          (
            FullSet
           ,[Promotion].[Promotion]
          )
       ,90
       ,[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[CountTopPromos] AS 
    Count(TopX)                  //<<<<<<<<<<<< CONTEXT LACKING HERE  <<<<<<<
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[CountTopPromos]} ON 0
 ,{TopX} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Currently it returns the following:

[image]

I'd like CountTopPromos to be in the context of the year so the desired output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: What is your requirement? I understand you want to show "TopX across all time" on the rows. But what should the measure be? I assume you do NOT want to include row context, as then the count would always be 1.to s so that , but use a measure that hows how many of

Comment: @FrankPl agreed OP was a little vague. I've edited and hopefully more precise now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sets are evaluated before the axes are defined (see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641868/logical-order-an-mdx-query-is-processed)), you cannot get row context into the calculation if you use the named set `TopX`. You could, however, copy its definition into the definition of `[Measures].[CountTopPromos]`, replacing `[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS` with `[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember`:

```
  MEMBER [Measures].[CountTopPromos] AS 
    Count(    
        Generate
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].currentMember
         ,TopPercent
          (
              [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            * 
              Extract
              (
                FullSet
               ,[Promotion].[Promotion]
              )
           ,90
           ,[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
          )
        ) 
    )
```

delivers the result you want. And - as the `Generate` would loop over just one member here - you could omit that as well:

```
  MEMBER [Measures].[CountTopPromos] AS 
    Count(    
         TopPercent
          (
              [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            * 
              Extract
              (
                FullSet
               ,[Promotion].[Promotion]
              )
           ,90
           ,[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
          )
        )
```

and will get the same result.

Comment: +1 thanks frank. Yep I need to keep in mind conceptual execution order. Just thought of another possible solution that is quite elegant - have posted below - what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that is quite pretty:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[CountTopPromos] AS 
  Count
  (
    Intersect
    (
      {
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember * [Promotion].[Promotion].MEMBERS
      }
     ,TopX
    )
  )
```