# MDX - NON EMPTY function faster?

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

I was under the assumption that `NON EMPTY` clause must be avoided whenever possible. So, I was in for a shock when I accidentally  found that it actually made the query much faster!

Sample this:

```
select 
[Measures].[Count Of Requests] on 0,
([Client].[Client Number].children , [Date].[Year].children) on 1
from [MyCube]
```

--19 seconds on a hot cache

```
select 
[Measures].[Count Of Requests] on 0,
non empty ([Client].[Client Number].children , [Date].[Year].children) on 1
from [MyCube]
```

--5 seconds on a **cold** cache(Consistently)

Isn't `NON EMPTY` recursive? Is it because of local cache size?

Comment: Hi sourav - I've added my "answer" which isn't a definite answer. +1 for the question as I'm interested to know the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Do you use the `NON EMPTY` axis expression, or the `NonEmpty()` function? From your question, I am not sure which one you are using.

Comment: @FrankPl - I am not talking about the function. `NON EMPTY` expression is that one I had used.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that`NON EMPTY` is applied at the very end of the script's process. See previous question/answer here:
[Logical order an MDX query is processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641868/logical-order-an-mdx-query-is-processed)

So effectively everything is returned and then before rendering results to grid or client application the `NON EMPTY` instruction means that null tuples on either rows or columns are discarded.

If your first script is returning a lot of data then does it take the extra time for the render process to complete?

Another interesting article re. `NON EMPTY` is here:
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/2996/non-empty-vs-nonempty-to-the-death

Comment: Yes, it is huge(mostly null) result set returned without the clause. I guess some optimization or parallel processing goes on inside the engine.

Comment: My answer could well be the reason then - it takes time to render the results into a table.

Comment: Makes sense. But any way to confirm this?

Comment: Just an update..it is 276029 and 20108 rows returned in the cases above.