# mdx query is taking for more time than sql

Tags: mdx, geospatial, data-warehouse, olap, mondrian

i have converted sql analysis to mdx analysis and found that mdx is far more expensive in term of execution time than sql. below is the sql which i am trying to convert to mdx

```html
select  inc.incident_id,inc.incident_start_time, inc.incident_end_time,inc_type.incident_type,inc.incident_desc,st_x(inc.the_geom) as incident_lon, st_y(inc.the_geom) as incident_lat,inc_type.class_name as incident_class, inc_type.incident_image  ,fir.modus_operandi, fir.fir_status, fir.fir_serial_no as fir_id  from analyst_mdx.incident as inc  join analyst_mdx.incident_types as inc_type on inc.incident_type = inc_type.incident_type_id left outer join analyst_mdx.fir_details as fir on inc.fir_no = fir.fir_no  join analyst_mdx.district on (st_contains(district.the_geom, inc.the_geom) and district.district_id=1)  where inc.incident_type in ('10','8','14','11','5','9','19','21','6','7','16','3','4','12','20','13','1','2','23','17','18')  and ((inc.incident_start_time between '2012-01-29T00:00:00'  and '2014-12-29T23:59:59')) order by incident_start_time, incident_end_time
```

and this is the fact tables are interconnected

[image]
now let me show you the mdx which i have made

```html
with member [Measures].[incident_type] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_type")'  
  member [Measures].[incident_desc] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_desc")'
  member [Measures].[incident_class] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_class")'
  member [Measures].[incident_image] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_image")'
  member [Measures].[modus_operandi] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("modus_operandi")'
  member [Measures].[fir_status] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_status")'
  member [Measures].[fir_id] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_id")'
  member [Measures].[date_start_time] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_start_time")'
  member [Measures].[the_geom] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom")'
  member [Measures].[date_end_time] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_end_time")'
  member [time].[newtime] as 'Aggregate({([time].[all  periods].[2012].[4].[15] : [time].[all  periods].[2012].[4].[30]),([time].[all  periods].[2012].[5]:[time].[all  periods].[2012].[12]) ,([time].[all  periods].[2013]),([time].[all  periods].[2014].[1] : [time].[all  periods].[2014].[6]),([time].[all  periods].[2014].[7].[1] : [time].[all  periods].[2014].[7].[15])})'
select {[Measures].[incident_type], [Measures].[incident_desc], [Measures].[incident_class],[Measures].[incident_image], [Measures].[modus_operandi], [Measures].[fir_status],[Measures].[fir_id], [Measures].[the_geom], [Measures].[date_start_time],[Measures].[date_end_time], [Measures].[incident_count]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY Filter([incident].[incident_id].Members, ST_Contains([district].[all district].[1].Properties("the_geom"),[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom"))) ON ROWS
from [pin_mapping]
where ([time].[newtime])
```

maximum record for a table is 65 thousand, sql executes in not more than 3 seconds and mdx takes more than 10 minutes. my entire olap concepts fails with it. can anyone explain me where i am going wrong ?

this is the cube that i am using...

```html
<Schema name="analyst_haryana">
  <Cube name="pin_mapping" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="pin_mapping_fact_table" schema="analyst_mdx"></Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="incident_id" name="incident">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="true" allMemberName="all incident" primaryKey="incident_id">
        <Table name="incident" schema="analyst_mdx"> </Table>
        <Level name="incident_id" column="incident_id" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
          <Property name="the_geom" column="the_geom" type="Geometry"></Property>
          <Property name="incident_type" column="incident_desc" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="incident_desc" column="incident_desc" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="fir_status" column="fir_status" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="incident_image" column="incident_image" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="modus_operandi" column="incident_desc" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="incident_class" column="incident_desc" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="date_start_time" column="date_start_time" type="String"></Property>
          <Property name="date_end_time" column="date_end_time" type="String"></Property>
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="TimeDimension" foreignKey="time_id" name="time">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="true" allMemberName="all  periods" primaryKey="time_id">
        <Table name="aux_dates" schema="analyst_mdx"></Table>
        <Level name="year" column="the_year" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never"></Level>
  <Level name="quarter" column="the_quarter" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters" hideMemberIf="IfParentsName"></Level>
        <Level name="month" column="the_month" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="IfParentsName"></Level>
        <Level name="day" column="the_day" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="IfParentsName"></Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="district_id" name="district">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="true" allMemberName="all district" primaryKey="district_id">
        <Table name="district" schema="analyst_mdx"></Table>
        <Level name="district_id" column="district_id" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfParentsName">
          <Property name="the_geom" column="the_geom" type="Geometry"></Property>
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="incident_type_id" name="incident_type">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="true" allMemberName="all incident _types" primaryKey="incident_type_id">
        <Table name="incident_types" schema="analyst_mdx"></Table>
        <Level name="incident_type_id" column="incident_type_id" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never"></Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="fir_serial_no" name="fir_details">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="true" allMemberName="all status" primaryKey="fir_serial_no">
        <Table name="fir_details" schema="analyst_mdx"></Table>
        <Level name="fir_status" column="fir_status" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never"></Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="incident_count" column="incident_count" datatype="Numeric" aggregator="count" visible="true"></Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Comment: - please try to simplify your questions. I'm not saying they are too difficult to answer but just quickly scanning over them there is too much detail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly sure, since I don't have the execution plans, but here goes nothing..

1. You have a well tuned SQL query on top which is doing set computation, which SQL Server is good at. And since the size of table is relatively small, it is bound to be fast. On the other hand, in the MDX query, you are actually doing cell-by-cell computation(due to use of `CURRENTMEMBER` function. The analysis engine sucks at it! Thus it is bound to be slow.
2. You are using the `NON EMPTY` function, which basically iterates through each and every row and filters out the EMPTY ones. This adds to the overhead on the engine. Run the query by removing the `NON EMPTY` clause, and see if it brings down the execution time(Though, I have observed that [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27107370/2993606) `NON EMPTY` clause actually improves rendering time)

The cube design must be revisited here. All the calculated members must be tried to be put as attributes of the dimensions involved, if possible.

Comment: @sourav..actually my case is, i want all the properties of level incident_id of dimension incident and i want to filter the result for a particular district and for a time range for the cube mentioned above...is there any other way to achieve the same without doing cell-by-cell computation i.e. without using the CURRENTMEMBER..???

Answer (score 0):

Enable the mondrian slow sql query log (done in log4j.xml) and see which query is the issue.

See if it is one query, or simply that mondrian is executing 1000's.

If the latter review your approxRowCount options in the schema as well as uniqueMembers options.  Possibly post the schema and results of the above changes so we can understand more.  There's also the (deprecated) highcardinality option.

Comment: i am using geomondrian...can you please brief me with how to enable the mondrian slow query log..

Comment: It's just an entry in log4j.xml. Copy and paste it from the one in the Pentaho BI server for an example.