# Order of execution in an MDX statement?

Tags: ssas, mdx

Just like there is a well-defined order of execution in a SQL statement, I am interested in knowing the order of execution in a typical MDX statement. i.e. I know `NON EMPTY` and `NonEmpty()` behave very differently in terms of when they are applied to the sets. Similarly, the order of execution is different for `HAVING` and `FILTER`. I am looking for a holistic answer that includes all the keywords in MDX. The list in which I am interested is

```
AXIS()
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
NAMED SET
CALCULATED MEMBERS
EXISTS
EXISTING    
NON EMPTY
NONEMPTY()
GENERATE
STRTOMEMBER
LEAD
AGGREGATE
EXISTS
IFF
CASE
HAVING
```

[There is a question on SO asking the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26641868/2993606) but I want some more information, hence a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical order an MDX query is processed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641868/logical-order-an-mdx-query-is-processed)

Comment: Hello Sourav. You commented on my previous question that this is effectively a duplicate of...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641868/logical-order-an-mdx-query-is-processed ...

Comment: Thanks @whytheq! Happy to know that an answer already exists but sadly their aren't much resources on the net.

Comment: @whytheq - I would like to add a few more keywords/functions into that. Do you want me to edit this question or can you add a few more into yours?

Comment: you could reference that previous question in this question and then add in the extra keywords that you need adding. Not sure if we'll get any help on this!