# Filter in WHERE using Named Set

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to use an aggregated named set to filter queries in MDX? I don't want the set items in the result set so moved it to the WHERE, however this seems to cause all measures to return (null).

First, I build a set using a couple of members from a staff hierarchy:

```
WITH 
  SET [Combined] as {
   [Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[04],
   [Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[06]
  }
```

Then I aggregate that set into a new member:

```
  MEMBER [Staff].[Group].[Group Combo] AS Aggregate([Combined])
```

Usually I would then use this in my query as a reporting area, possibly with hierarchize (depending on the query) and everything is fine. However this time I needed to filter the data based on this combination of members e.g:

```
WHERE ([Staff].[Group].[Group Combo])
```

This gave me (null) values and if I used [Combined] I received a cyclical reference error, however using the below worked fine:

```
WHERE ({[Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[04],[Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[06]})
```

Am I overlooking something here? Or using the wrong approach? Maybe it is just a quirk of the cube I am querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the behaviour is related to the order in which the processor is executing the clauses within your query:

[Logical order an MDX query is processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641868/logical-order-an-mdx-query-is-processed)

`WHERE` happens before `WITH`

You mentioned that the following works fine - specifying explicit members in the where clause it is pretty standard *and fast*:

```
WHERE ({[Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[04],[Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[06]})
```

You could add it to a sub-select just as it is on the 0 axis:

```
SELECT
 ...
 ...
FROM
  (
    SELECT
       {[Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[04],[Staff].[Group].[Practice Group].&[06]} ON 0
    FROM [YourCube]
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be it and it would certainly fit the behaviour I saw. In terms of approach, is there a better option? Can you create a set in a sub-select which effectively limits your cube space for the main query?

Comment: sub-select is another way to filter. Sub-selects also bring with them some unusual behaviour. What you cannot do is create a member in a with clause and then use it in a sub-select ... although I guess that is sort of intuitive.